# Removing everything but the actual Report from the iFrame in Jasper Server Community Edition

Tags: api, http, iframe, jasperserver

I am using Jasper Server community edition 5.2. I am embedding these reports in to my web application using iframes. I am able to remove the jasper logo and menus by passing 'decorate=no" parameter to the url of the iFrame. However I want to get rid of the scroll buttons and export buttons and have my own.

I know this can be achieved in jasper pro edition by getting rid of the dashboard, but how can this be achieved in the community edition?